# Lookup producing #Error result in SSRS report result

Tags: reporting-services

I'm doing a 'straight' lookup in my table report in SSRS. The lookup references app id to pull a state value:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Acct_num.Value,Fields!CLIENT_APP_ID.Value,Fields!STATE.Value, "DataSet2").
```

My research shows others getting a #Error result but there's always been something 'else' involved such as a calculation or IIF statement(s). Mine is just a simple lookup. I've confirmed the app ID values for both datasets is numeric. Dataset 1 is an Excel table and Dataset 2 is a query result. There are a couple other values I need to pull from Dataset 2 but the app ID is the unique value I'm using and I get the #Error result for the other fields as well.

Cue the Twilight Zone music...

Comment: Are you getting an error or warning in the **Error List** at the bottom? You're comparing **Acct_Num** to **Client App ID** - are you sure they're the same **data type**? Are you sure that **Acct Num** isn't NULL or has multiple values (due to Grouping)?

Comment: And are you sure your dataset is DataSet2 as this is case sensitive?

Comment: I assume there isn't actually a full stop at the end of your expression. Does DataSet2 contain a complete and unique list of client account numbers?

Comment: Great questions and 'yes' to all. These are both numeric fields and populated for all instances (no NULL values). I created the Lookup by click i.e. I did not type in the values to preclude typo/case sensitivity. The error msg indicates an issue with the comparison which is why I'm stumped as everything I perceive should match. I'm 'sensing' the issue might be related to an excel table to a query results comparison but have no argument to support this feeling.

Comment: Update. I finally got some time to explore my suspicion regarding datasource difference between Excel table and Oracle query results. I exported the query results and adjusted the DataSet2 to this Excel table. And....you guessed it. No more '#Error' message with my Lookup expression. So, moving forward but sure would like an explanation to calm the academic in me. :>)